# User profile misalignment

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, responsive-design

[Profile Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186381)

[image: profile page with misalignment highlighted in red box]

2021/11/3 update, this has been fixed.

Comment: I don’t see the first one as a misalignment. There’s no indication that the left sidebar (with “Communities” and “Top network posts”) is necessarily a quarter of the width of the profile. As for the second misalignment: I think this is how far Aaron got with [redesigning the profile page](/q/368661/289905). The lower “box”, i.e. anything from “Communities” and the badges down, has [very different box model metrics and alignment](//i.stack.imgur.com/VtlMV.png) when [compared to the top part](//i.stack.imgur.com/ix1pC.png).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks, you can post an answer for this, and add a quote for _"this is how far Aaron got with redesigning the profile page"_.

Comment: Well, it’s just a guess.

Comment: (Note to future readers: my first comment refers to [an earlier revision](/revisions/369733/3) of this post.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m still working on the bottom 3/4 of the profile pages. All those boxes will be aligned, I promise. ✌️

Comment: You promised but I hope this promise doesn't extends to 2 years :P

Comment: Wait, is two years a long time??? 

Comment: 2 years is 3-4 times faster than the expected 6-8 years :)